# Having trouble making a XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make an XMLHttpRequest, however, I am having issues. The page keeps refreshing automatically even when returning false or using e.preventDefault(). I'm trying to get cities to eventually pass through an options block. (I've started the option section and will complete it after I figure out the get request issue.) I'm trying to do this using pure Javascript because I've already done it using Angular and Node. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form id="citySearchForm" method="get" onSubmit="return searchFormFunc();">
         <div>
             <p>Choose a city:</p>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a city" id="getCitiesInput" name="city">
             <input type="submit" value="submit">
         </div>
         <div id="weather"></div
         <p><span id="temp"></span></p
         <p><span id="wind"></span></p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var citySearch = document.getElementById("citySearchForm");

// citySearch.addEventListener("submit", searchFormFunc);

function searchFormFunc(e){

    cityName = document.getElementById('getCitiesInput').value;

    var searchCityLink = "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=";
    var search = searchCityLink.concat(cityName);

    console.log("link : " + search);

    var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var r = JSON.parse(xhr.response || xhr.responseText); // IE9 has no property response, so you have to use responseText

            console.log(r);
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
  };

    xhr.open("GET", link, true);
    xhr.send(null);

    var r = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

     return false;

 //  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: First of all, the html you append in innerHTML is incorrect. see option tag. Note that a form auto submits if there is an error in the js. Do you need the form? since you are submitting from Ajax anyway

Comment: Here is how to properly use [Ajax](http://idiallo.com/javascript/ajax-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying that you want this to be an async request. So you need to parse your response inside of the `onreadystatechange` or `onload`.

```
function ajax(url, callback) {
    var xhr;

    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0", 
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0", 
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
                        "Microsoft.XmlHttp"]

         for(var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                break;
            }
            catch(e){}
         } // end for
    }

    /** Here you can specify what should be done **/
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState < 4) {
            return;
        }

        if(xhr.status !== 200) {
            return;
        }

        // all is well  
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xhr);
        }           
    }

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send('');
}
```

*Answer from documentation by [user6123921](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6123921)*

Answer (score -1):

1. You have to use `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`
2. you have to define an `onreadystatechange` event listener

```js
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var r = JSON.parse(xhr.response || xhr.responseText); // IE9 has no property response, so you have to use responseText

            console.log(r);

            /* do stuff with response */
        }
    };
```